# How to plot results of Dsolve

Tags: plotting

I could not figure out how to get a plot of the results of my coupled differential equations. I am sure that the equations are written correctly. I tried solving a basic Lotka Volterra set of equations but could't figure out how to graph the results of that either. Please Help!

a = 2;
b = 1;
c = 1;
d = 2;

```
DSolve[{x'[t] == a x[t] - b x[t] y[t], 
  y'[t] == -c y[t] + d x[t] y[t]}, {x[t], y[t]}, t]
```

I haven't read anything that made sense for graphing... I tried variations of this: `Plot[y[t] /. s, {t, 0, 10}]`

Comment: Right, but the initial conditions did not help.

Comment: DSolve[{x'[t] == a x[t] - b x[t] y[t], y'[t] == -c y[t] + d x[t] y[t],
   x[0] = 1, y[0] = 1}, {x[t], y[t]}, t]
Plot[y[t] /. s, {t, 0, 10}]

Comment: with parameters of course

Answer (score 4):

I do not understand why `NDSolve` can't be used here? What exactly is the issue? This is a simple use of `NDSolve`

```
a = 2; b = 1; c = 1; d = 2;
eq1 = x'[t] == a x[t] - b x[t] y[t];
eq2 = y'[t] == -c y[t] + d x[t] y[t];
sol = NDSolve[{eq1, eq2, x[0] == 1, y[0] == 1}, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 5}];
```

and plot it

```
Plot[{x[t] /. sol, y[t] /. sol}, {t, 0, 5}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"solution", None}, {t, {x[t], y[t]}}}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"x(t)", "y(t)"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume

```
equ1 = {x'[t] == a x[t] - b y[t] x[t],
        y'[t] == c x[t] y[t] - d y[t]}
```

Than `se2 = DSolve[equ1, {x, y}, t]`

Than plot is,

```
Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. se2 /. {C[1] -> 1, C[2] -> 1}], {t, -10,
   10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

This plot is taking exceptional time, so I took a very simple example as under,

```
equ = {x'[t] == -y[t] + 2,  y'[t] == x[t] - 1}
```

Plotting it ,

```
Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. se /. {C[1] -> 1, C[2] -> 1}], {t, -10, 
  10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Plot]

I hope it answers your question.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, but when I do just what you did, the plot is blank.

Comment: it is blank for which one..equ1 or equ ?

Comment: They are both blank.....

Comment: equ1 was taking exceptionally long time on my machine(2gb RAM) so I chose this simplified equation equ and it has corresponding plot.May be you made some mistake!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, but this doesn't work either, and I have a lot of memory...